# How to add newline symbol and multiplication symbol together in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trynig to create a matplotlib label where I can use both newline symbol and multiplication symbol. However, when I use them together then I only see multiplication symbol with '\n' as a part of text. The code that i use to create the symbol is below.

```
r"L1+\nL1$\times$L2"
```

Can someone point where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution was easier than I thought. All I had to do was to make a string as a combination of individual strings like `"L1+\n"+r'L1$\times$L2` and it works